# How to safley deal with iterators in loops?

Tags: c++, iterator

Hello I am asked in C++ primer 5th edition to "Write a function that takes three strings, s, oldVal, and
newVal. Using iterators, and the insert and erase functions replace all
instances of oldVal that appear in s by newVal. Test your function by
using it to replace common abbreviations, such as “tho” by “though” and
“thru” by “through”."

I've tried this:

```
void set_str(string& s, const string& oldVal, const string& newVal) {

    for (auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it) {
        auto it2 = oldVal.begin();
        for (; it2 != oldVal.end() && *it == *it2; ++it, ++it2)
            ;
        if (it2 == oldVal.end()) {
            it = s.erase(it - (oldVal.size()), it);
            it = s.insert(it, newVal.begin(), newVal.end());
            it += newVal.size();
        }

    }
}

int main() {

    string oldVal = "good";
    string newVal = "gud";
    string s = "C++ is really a good programming language, it is not only good in its performance \
but also good in dealing with real world problems";

    set_str(s, oldVal, newVal);

    cout << s << endl;

}
```

- The program works fine but I'd like to know whether manipulating iterators  in the function `set_str` are valid or I am triggering a UB? Thank you!. Any other suggestion is highly welcome.

This is the ouptut:

`C++ is really a gud programming language, it is not only gud in its performance
        but also gud in dealing with real world problems`

Comment: Yes, the code has undefined behaviour in some circumstances.   The first nested loop increments `it` based on the number of characters in `oldVal`, but `it` is an iterator from a completely different string (`s`).   It can cause `it` to pass the end of `s`.

Comment: @Peter: Thank you!

Comment: @Peter: Thank you again. Could you add an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You're close, but you're not quite there.

A problem arises when `oldVal` is at the end of the string.  You then position `it` at the end of the modified string and then increment it at the end of your `for` loop.  Result: UB (a segmentation fault when I tested it).  The same out-by-one error means that the logic is not quite right when there are multiple matches in the input string.

Fortunately, the solution is simple.  Just replace:

```
it += newVal.size();
```

with

```
it += newVal.size() - 1;
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ytqydJ9ldOpt31Xo) (try removing the -1 and rerunning the code).

---

**Edit:** As the OP points out, there is also a problem if `oldVal` is longer than the number of characters remaining in `s` and matches the remaining characters in `s`.  To deal with this, just check if `oldVal` is longer than the number of characters remaining in `s` each time round the outer loop and exit if so:

```
for (auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it) {
    if (oldVal.length() > (size_t) (s.end() - it))
        return;
    ...
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/k7xyq3iTMenoBDL1)

---

**Edit #2:** To address oldVal being empty or newVal being empty, here, I sincerely hope, is the final, fully robust version:

```
using namespace std;

void set_str(string& s, const string& oldVal, const string& newVal) {

    if (oldVal.length() == 0)
        return;

    int delta_it;
    for (auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); it += delta_it) {
        if (oldVal.length() > (size_t) (s.end() - it))
            return;

        auto it2 = oldVal.begin();
        for (; it2 != oldVal.end() && *it == *it2; ++it, ++it2)
            ;

        delta_it = 1;
        if (it2 == oldVal.end()) {
            it = s.erase(it - (oldVal.size()), it);
            it = s.insert(it, newVal.begin(), newVal.end());
            delta_it = newVal.size();
        }
    }
}
```

The usual caveat about not using `using namespace std` applies.

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nOhsyX7So2A43bp6)

Answer (score 1):

The code has undefined behaviour in some circumstances.

The first nested loop increments `it` based on the number of characters in `oldVal`, but `it` is an iterator from a completely different string (`s`). That loop can therefore cause `it` to reach and pass the end of `s`.

Obviously that won't happen in all circumstances but it would not be difficult to construct an example where `it` is incremented until it is equal to `s.end()` and is dereferenced.

Comment: But would elaborate an example? Thank you anyway

Comment: If function is called with `s` containing the string `"a"` and `oldVal` containing any stringof length 2  with the first character `'a`', that loop deferences an end iterator on the first iteration of the outer loop.   The function does not prevent that.  The undefined behaviour occurs before any access of `newVal`, so it doesn't matter what is passed for that.    As I said, constructing an example that triggers undefined behaviour is trivial.   You may not intend the function to be called that way, but there is nothing preventing that.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing this code using indexes is easier and safer than using iterators the fact that a version like `string::insert` or `string::erase` with indexes it doesn't matter for the version taking `std::size_t count` because it is guaranteed to do its work up to the size. Which means not de-referencing or indexing non-existent elements. But as you asked using iterators, it is a bit complicated to assume every possible input of the user and to ensure not incrementing `end` or decrementing `begin` iterators.

I've already seen the answers to exercises of "C++ 5ed" but it is also causing UB under some circumstances.

However I've tried to elaborate an example for you handling the most possible cases of input strings:

```
void set_str(string& s, const string& oldVal, const string& newVal) {
    if (s.empty() || oldVal.empty() || oldVal.size() > s.size())
        return;
    for (auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ) {
        if (oldVal.size() > (size_t)(s.end() - it) )
            return ;
        if (string(it, it + oldVal.size()) == oldVal) {
            cout << "found: " << (it - s.begin()) << endl;
            it = s.erase(it, it + oldVal.size());
            it = s.insert(it, newVal.begin(), newVal.end());
            it += newVal.size();
        }
        else
            ++it;
    }
}
```

As you can see in the first line we check whether `s` is empty so no need to do the rest so return directly also no need to continue if `oldVal` is empty which means nothing to continue. But `newVal` can empty in which case we want to remove only the instances of `oldVal` in `s`.

- Also if the size of `oldVal` is greater than the `s`'s return also directly for the fact that any sub-string is shorter than the string being it a sub-string form.
- I've used only one `for` loop to check whether `it` is one-past-end or not, also in its header it doesn't increment `it` because if `oldVal` has been found then for sure it'd replaced with `newVal` and thus updated and there's no need to advance it. We only advance it if `oldVal` hadn't been found in `s`.
- Also if the size of `oldVal` is greater than the sub-string denoted by the range of iterators `s.end() - it` inside the loop will cause the function to return which means it is nearly at the end of `s` and we don't want to increment it past-last-element. Which means `it + oldVal.size` is `n` positions past-end iterator, which means UB. This ensures that `it` should stop advancing at position `s.end() - oldVal.size()`.
- The interesting thing is I didn't used an inner loop build a sub-string from `s` starting at position denoted by `it` up to the it + `oldVal.size()` but instead We create a temporary string from the range of characters denoted by iterators `it, it + oldVal.size()` from `s` and then compare it with `oldVal`:
- If the temporary string is equal to `oldVal` then we remove it from `s` (`it, it + oldVal.size()`) and update `it` to position the first character after erasure.
- We insert `newVal` before that position then we increment `it` `newVal`'s positions. It doesn't matter whether `newVal` is empty or not.
- Otherwise if `oldVal` hadn't been found in `s` we simply increment `it`.
- Remember this: We increment `it` if and only if `oldVal` was  not found which means no erasure or insertion thus it was not invalidated. If it is found we handle positioning it but not incrmenting it again in the `for-loop`

Now it is time to mess up with `set_str` in the driver program:

```
    int main() {

        string oldVal = "a";
        string newVal = "";
        string s = "aa";

        set_str(s, oldVal, newVal);

        std::cout << "s: " << s << std::endl;

    }
```

Try as many inputs for `s, oldVal, newVal` and see whether it causes a UB or not.